# Banner overlaps Sub-Menu Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

I just upgraded Wordpress to version 3.5.1 and it messed up something in my site that now the Submenus load but are instantly hidden behind the Banner (They load up but are quickly hidden). I have tried a few modifications here and there but nothing (Now I may have messed it even more).

I think it's in the CSS File.

Here is a link to the site: http://www.fiestacolegial.com and the Submenus that are meant to appear go below MULTIMEDIA, NOTICIAS, SOBRE NOSOTROS.

Here is a link to the CSS File: http://pastie.org/6381132

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that jQuery 1.9 is causing trouble with a plugin that handles this interaction.

This tutorial should show you how to use version 1.8 of jQuery instead: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/replace-default-wordpress-jquery-script-with-google-library/

Comment: I just tried it and still have the same problem. Where exactly on the function.php should I paste that code?

Comment: Anywhere in functions.php should do the trick :) though, your website is still loading the newer version of jQuery. Could you post the contents of your functions.php file?
You can use this: http://pastebin.com/

Comment: Strange, I tried and it works alright for me. I downloaded the free version of the theme you're using to test as well with no problems.

While leaving that in the footer, is there a file called 'default-options.php'? Inside there's 'jquery'=> true, if you try changing to false and see what happens.

Comment: I just tried that and still the issue keeps going. If you go to [link](http://www.fiestacolegial.com) do you see the submenus when you hover over?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't think much else beyond that :/ I'm nearly certain it's down to the newer jQuery version being used, but without being able to change it leaves it an issue.
Really sorry, that's all I can say. Hopefully someone else can resolve this!